# Javascript change fields value by name

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a form where some fields have the same element name. Is there a way to change the value of all the fields with the same name?

Comment: Note: If they are radio buttons, they are supposed to have the same name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1) Use [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) to put the elements in an array.
2) Loop over the array and set each element's value.

code:

```
var els=document.getElementsByName("yourElementNameHere");
for (var i=0;i<els.length;i++) {
els[i].value = "yourDesiredValueHere";}
```

If you only want to change the elements with that name in the form, use the form instead of `document`, example: `document.getElementById("yourFormID").getElementsByName(...)`

Comment: [`getElementsByName` seems not to be supported by IE or Opera!](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125)

Comment: @Felix Kling: that page reads "incomplete and incorrect" (against W3C DOM2 specs) yet it supported.

Comment: Anyway, i dont like this approach, too global

Comment: @user205376: *Incomplete and incorrect* sounds very much like *don't use that method!* imo.

Comment: @Felix Kling: check out what "incomplete and incorrect" means as outlined by PPK (this method is **very** old and was IE-specific before adoption by W3C :-)

Answer (score 1):

### sample form

```
<form name="form1">
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="button1">
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="button2">
    <input type="button" name="buttons" value="button3">
</form>
```

### script

```
var form = document.form1;    // form by name 
var form = document.forms[0]; // same as above, first form in the document
var elements = form.buttons; // elements with same name attribute become a HTMLCollection
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) 
   elements[i].value = elements[i].value.replace("button", "buttoff");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yGV3R/

Answer (score 1):

you can do more simple with JQUERY 
example :

**html**

```
<div id="form">
<input type="text" name="myinput" vale="yussan" />
</div>
```

**js**

```
var value = $('#form input[name=myinput]').val()
```